# C#/dotnet - How to detect if a previously executed process is running on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process

I have a `dotnet console application` which executes other `dotnet console applications` *only if they are not running*.

In windows if I run like following (via `process.Start()`):

```
dotnet run Bookstore.SendSignUpEmails
dotnet run Bookstore.SetDatabaseFields
```

It set process names on Windows like `Bookstore.SendSignUpEmails` and `Bookstore.SetDatabaseFields` where I can find them easily by `Process.GetProcessesByName` and detect if they are still running or not.

But on `Linux` processes named `dotnet` and I cannot find any metadata around them. So I cannot determine if I should run those projects again or not.

[image]

So, how can I detect whether a project executed before is still running or not? Should I maybe write to a file then check it there? I still see there can be some race conditions and not very safe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you running the `dotnet` program through `Process.Start()` rather than the actual compiled binary of your application?

Comment: I don’t have reference to each other. All of them independently running

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Comment: How do you suggest me to run a dotnet program from another one?

Comment: When you compile the application you get an executable binary. Can't you just run that file directly, rather than going through the dotnet cli?

Comment: I have multiple applications not a single one. I can't get how your solution will work here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250127/discussion-between-teoman-shipahi-and-gunr2171).